# inline function and class and header file

Tags: c++, class, inline, one-definition-rule

1. Will any function defined in the header file automatically be inline?
2. If I declare a function in a class and give the definition outside using keyword inline, will this function be inline? If it is, why this does not against the law that inline function should be given the body at declaration?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131771/inline-keyword-in-member-function-definition

Comment: @JBentley - however, that answer incorrectly applies the ODR.

Comment: @JBentley - I take it back. The ODR addresses multiple definitions in different translation units as well as in the same translation unit. Now I have to back out all the things I've been saying in comments below. :-(

Answer (score 8):

Any function defined inside a class definition is inline. Any function marked `inline` is also inline.

```
class C {
    int f() { return 3; } // inline
    int g();
    int h();
}


inline int C::g() { return 4; } // inline
int C::h() { return 5; } // not inline
```

If all this code is in a header and that header is used in more than one translation unit you'll get a complaint that `C::h` has more than one definition. `C::f` and `C::g` are okay because they're inline.  That's the primary role of `inline` these days: to permit defining the same function in multiple places (provided the definitions are "the same").

Answer (score 5):

> is it that any function defined in the header file will automatically be inline?

No, you should make any function defined outside of class body inline by hands. Otherwise, most likely you would get [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) violation (if include header in several translation units).

ISO C++11

> 3.2 One definition rule
>
> 1: No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type, or template.
>
> [...]
>
> 4: **Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function** or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic required. The definition can appear explicitly in the program, it can be found in the standard or a user-defined library, or (when appropriate) it is implicitly defined (see 12.1, 12.4 and 12.8). An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used.

---

> if I declare a function in a class and give the definition outside using keyword inline, will this function be inline? If it is, why this does not against the law that inline function should be given the body at declaration?

There are several ways to do member function inline:

First, according to 7.1.2/3:

> **A function defined within a class definition is an inline function**. The inline specifier shall not appear on a block scope function declaration.90 If the inline specifier is used in a friend declaration, that declaration shall be a definition or the function shall have previously been declared inline.

```
struct First
{
    void first(){}
};
```

Second, Third and Fourth, according to 9.3/3:

> An **inline** member function (whether static or non-static) may also be defined outside of its class definition **provided either its declaration in the class definition or its definition outside of the class definition declares the function as inline**. [ Note: Member functions of a class in namespace scope have external linkage. Member functions of a local class (9.8) have no linkage. See 3.5. —end note ]

```
struct STF
{
    void second();
    inline void third();
    inline void fourth();
};

inline void STF::second(){}
void STF::third(){}
inline void STF::fourth(){}
```

Comment: The problem would simply be multiple definitions of the same thing. This has nothing to do with the ODR, which requires that when multiple definitions are allowed, they have to be the same. Also, it's not just non-member functions, but **any** function that is not defined inside a class definition.

Comment: @PeteBecker. "This has nothing to do with the ODR" - really? Could you please elaborate how ODR is not related to "problem would simply be multiple definitions of the same thing" ?

Comment: Really. If you have two non-inline definitions of the same name that's an error; always has been, always will be. In the context of this question, the ODR says that when you have two definitions of the same function both marked `inline` they have to be "the same". So `inline int f() { return 3; } inline int f() { return 4; }` violates the ODR. `int f() { return 3; } int f() { return 3; }` is simply two definitions of the same thing, and an error.

Comment: This question is not about function templates. There's a whole bunch of discussion possible about function templates, but that's not appropriate here. But, yes, function templates are subject to the ODR.

Comment: @PeteBecker, "If you have two non-inline definitions of the same name that's an error; always has been, always will be." - that is **ODR** - I have added reference to ISO in answer.

Comment: No. If you have the definition `int f() { return 3; }` in two different translation units it's an error. Nothing to do with the ODR. You've also omitted 95% of the text that defines the ODR. There's a lot of stuff that comes after that paragraph.

Comment: "No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type, or template" - that is first item in "3.2 One definition rule". I really dont see how that is "Nothing to do with the ODR".

Comment: You're right: I was treating it too narrowly. Most of the time, "ODR problem" is used to refer to definitions of a class or an inline function that are not the same; but it is a catchall for the various rules about when and how the same name can be defined in multiple places.

Comment: Frankly, for me ODR is first of all disallowance of multiple definitions (as I read in TC++PL). And yes, there are some exceptions like inline functions + special rules which should be fulfilled in order to legitimately use such exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

`inline` is a "hint", insofar as the compiler doesn't have to honor it.  It can make things inline that you don't mark inline and doesn't have to inline things that you mark as inline.

By that, I mean you shouldn't rely on it.  Many recommend that you don't even use it as it is misleading.  Most modern compilers completely ignore it.

The only practical use is to allow you to put static implementations into a header.  Whether or not that is a good thing to do is arguable.

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean the hint is automatically given when a definition happened in the header file even the keyword inline is not used?