# If I declare and define a function inside the header file, does it matter to make the function inline?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, inline

I am inside `struct T { ... };`. If I declare and define a function inside the header file, does it matter if I make the function `inline`? I mean, isn't it by default considered `inline` in this case? It seems `inline` is more of a suggestion to the compiler. So maybe, in this case, all it means is a stronger suggestion (?) Does your answer depend on whether or not the function is actually a template function?

EDIT:
Here are a few related quotes from [C++ Referece](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline):

According to the following quote, the **original** intent of the `inline` was as I said it here. Not sure when/if it is changed, and if/how I can the original meaning back.

> The original intent of the inline keyword was to serve as an indicator to the optimizer that inline substitution of a function is preferred over function call, that is, instead of executing the function call CPU instruction to transfer control to the function body, a copy of the function body is executed without generating the call. This avoids overhead created by the function call (passing the arguments and retrieving the result) but it may result in a larger executable as the code for the function has to be repeated multiple times.

According to the following quote, `inline` only **suggests** something to the compiler.

> Since this meaning of the keyword inline is non-binding, compilers are free to use inline substitution for any function that's not marked inline, and are free to generate function calls to any function marked inline. Those optimization choices do not change the rules regarding multiple definitions and shared statics listed above.

So if in the current C++ Standard, `inline` means something else, how can I suggest to the compiler to inline an implementation (with the inline meaning that I quoted above).

Comment: A member function defined within the class definition is implicitly `inline`, if that's what you are asking. I don't understand the part about "suggestion".

Comment: Not sure if [A: inline function and class and header file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15865729) is up to [tag:language-lawyer] standards, but it does quote the standard while answering what seems to be this question.

Comment: By "suggestion", I mean compiler does not have to do it. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Doesn't have to do what?

Comment: inline the method

Comment: @Koosha The `inline` keyword has no influence -- not even as a suggestion -- on whether or not a C++ function is inlined by the compiler. It's been that way for over two decades.

Comment: *"Not sure when/if it is changed,"* -- I think it changed in the early 90s. It was definitely before the C++98 standard. Still, this is probably the wrong way to view that quote. It tries to explain the strange choice of `inline` to mean "multiple definitions are permitted", not to explain any C++ functionality.

Comment: *"if/how I can the original meaning back."* -- use an ancient compiler? You might even have to go back to an ancient C compiler, before C++ emerged as its own language. (It did emerge before the 1998 C++ standard.)

Comment: *"how can I suggest to the compiler to inline an implementation"* -- this is not supported by the standard, so if this is your real question, you might want to remove the "language-lawyer" tag. (There are compiler-specific ways to do this, even though usually the compiler is better than the programmer at deciding which functions should be inlined.)